# Python & tkinter separator with label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to insert a separator with a label on it, much like what would happen with:

```
f = LabelFrame(root, text='hi')
f.pack(fill=X,padx=5, pady=5)
```

What I would like is for the separator to be labeled like the above - there aren't many options to change a separator line

```
ttk.Separator(root).pack(fill=X)
```

Is there anyway to overlay a label onto a separator or have a zero sized labelframe?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396900/python-tkinter-ttk-separator-with-label)?

Comment: Yes, no idea why my search never found that!! But thank you

Comment: I was a bit too quick marking as duplicate - I am using the packing method :(